# PHP script doesn't receive file I send to it with AJAX using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I searched for the solution to this everywhere already. People do this all the same yet it doesn't work for me.

The relevant HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="import">Import</button>
```

The relevant Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){

                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append("file", file);
                    alert(fd.get("file"));

                    $.ajax({
                        //URL of the PHP file
                        url: "readFile.php",

                        //fd will be send
                        data:fd,

                        //json is the type that should be returned
                        dataType: "json",

                        //To prevent processing
                        cache:false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,

                        //when successful
                        success: function( data ) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

And lastly, the PHP I wrote to find the bug: (named readFile.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    echo json_encode("great");
}else {
    echo json_encode("bad");
}
?>
```

This code works, except for the part where the PHP should have received the file.

That PHP checks whether it received the file. If it were there it would print out "great", yet it always prints out (console log) "bad", when I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that need to be changed in your client-side JavaScript in order for this to work.

1. The `file` variable currently holds a reference to the `HTMLInputElement`, and not the selected binary file(s). Elements of type `file` provide a `files` property ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)) that contains the list of files selected for upload. To upload the (single) selected one, retrieve the first element like so:

   ```
    fd.append("file", file.files[0]);
   ```
2. If no parameter is given, jQuery’s `$.ajax()` method will default to sending a GET request ([jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). Per [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), a “payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics”. The underlying `XMLHttpRequest` API ignores any body for GET requests ([XHR spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method)). Instead, you may want to send a POST request which is suitable for uploading files ([PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.post-method.php)). Make sure to add the HTTP method as follows:

   ```
    $.ajax({
      // existing configuration
      method: 'POST'
    });
   ```

This should be it! Please also note that the `cache` property doesn’t need to be set, as POST requests aren’t cached anyway.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!